# why alertDialog is not working in android application?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to give some alert text message while some initilizing work is going on. 
So i have used following code in my main activity in android application.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("main","=================init===============");
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title Info");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Initilizing so please wait....");
    alertDialog.show();
    // calling some initilizing function from jni which takes some time
    alertDialog.hide(); 
   }
```

when i run application i got that log in logcat but that alert dialog doesnt show..
i am not getting why this  not working?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling any time/resource consuming code inside your UI thread anyway. It sounds like this may be fixed with an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your initializing function, while creating the `AlertDialog` inside the `preExecution` and closing it in the `postExecution`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using AsyncTask method in android.
Create a class with a async

private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
        super.onPreExecute();
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainClass.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("msg....");
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Perform your JNI operation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        alertDialog.hide();

    }
}
```

In your class

AlertDialog alertDialog;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//Add following code

new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();

```
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because when you ask the alert dialog to .show() it's telling the framework to show the dialog the next time the system gets control (i.e. after your methods have returned control back to the application) and therefore the dialog displaying isn't done immediately.

Because you've called show and followed immediately by a hide inside this method, the dialog state will be in 'hide' when the application does try to draw it.

If you want to show and later hide the dialog you need to call hide at a later time such as on a timer or due to some callback from the alertDialog.  (Also make sure you're calling show and hide from the main thread)

Comment: my jni initilizing function takes some time to return control back them meanwhile why my control is not showing?

Comment: That just means you're blocking your `onCreate()`, your activity won't be shown until after `onCreate()` is finished.

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
dialogbox = new Dialog(alertdialog.this);
                dialogbox.setContentView(R.layout.exit_dialog_box);
                dialogbox.setTitle("");
                dialogbox.setCancelable(true);
                Button button = (Button) dialogbox.findViewById(R.id.Button);

                dialogbox.show();
```